# How can I test API endpoints with environment variables with MSW

Tags: testing, next.js, msw

I want to test marvel api endpoints that needs environment variables in Next.js but I get this error:

Error: ❌ Attempted to access a server-side environment variable on the client.

```
getHash src/services/api.ts:7:23
  5| const getTimestamp = () => Date.now().toString();
  6| const getHash = (timeStamp: string) =>
  7|   md5(timeStamp + env.MARVEL_API_PRIVATE_KEY + env.MARVEL_API_PUBLIC_KEY);
```

This is my env file:

```
import { createEnv } from '@t3-oss/env-nextjs';
import { z } from 'zod';

export const env = createEnv({
  server: {
    NODE_ENV: z.enum(['development', 'test', 'production']),
    MARVEL_API_PRIVATE_KEY: z.string(),
    MARVEL_API_PUBLIC_KEY: z.string(),
    MARVEL_API_URL: z.string().url(),
    PORT: z.coerce.number().default(3000),
  },

  client: {},

  runtimeEnv: {
    NODE_ENV: process.env.NODE_ENV,
    MARVEL_API_URL: process.env.MARVEL_API_URL,
    MARVEL_API_PUBLIC_KEY: process.env.MARVEL_API_PUBLIC_KEY,
    MARVEL_API_PRIVATE_KEY: process.env.MARVEL_API_PRIVATE_KEY,
    PORT: process.env.PORT,
  },
});
```

The service api function:

```
import md5 from 'md5';

import { env } from '@/env';

const getTimestamp = () => Date.now().toString();
const getHash = (timeStamp: string) =>
  md5(timeStamp + env.MARVEL_API_PRIVATE_KEY + env.MARVEL_API_PUBLIC_KEY);

const timeStamp = getTimestamp();
const hash = getHash(timeStamp);
const query = `ts=${timeStamp}&apikey=${env.MARVEL_API_PUBLIC_KEY}&hash=${hash}`;

export const getCharacters = async () => {
  const url = `${env.MARVEL_API_URL}/characters?limit=50&${query}`;
  const response = await fetch(url);
  const data = response.json();

  return data;
};
```

The component where this function is called:

```
import { CharacterCard } from '@/app/components/Characters';
import { env } from '@/env';
import { Character } from '@/models/character';
import { getCharacters } from '@/services/api';

import styles from './styles.module.css';

export const CharactersList = async () => {
  const characters = await getCharacters();

  console.log(
    'ENV',
    env.NODE_ENV,
    env.MARVEL_API_URL,
    env.MARVEL_API_PRIVATE_KEY,
    env.MARVEL_API_PUBLIC_KEY,
  );

  return (
    <section className={styles.charactersList}>
      {characters.data.results.map((character: Character) => (
        <CharacterCard key={character.id} character={character} />
      ))}
    </section>
  );
};
```

While running the application in localhost the env variables are printed in the console but don't understand why not in the testing api call.

And the msw handler:

```
import { HttpResponse, http } from 'msw';

export const handlers = [
  http.get('/characters', () => {
    return HttpResponse.json(
      {
        id: 1011334,
        name: '3-D Man',
      },
      { status: 200 },
    );
  }),
];
```

Comment: Where in your Next.js app these functions are called?

Answer (score 1):

You've not posted what is setup in your @/env dir, but at a guess I'd say you're not loading them properly.

You would typically have, and NextJS supports, having a `.env` file or `.env.local` in the root of your project (so not in any special dir). This is then automatically loaded into `process.env` for you to import.

So, you'd likely need to remove what you've got in your @/env dir (or just make it a .env file in the root of the project).

And then set it up:

```
KEY=VALUE
KEY2=VALUE2
```

And then you would reference them like:

```
console.log(process.env.KEY)
```

Additionally, and it may not be relevant here. But in NextJS to expose an env var publically, you need to prepend `NEXT_PUBLIC` so if you did want to use `MARVEL_API_PUBLIC_KEY` client side you would need to make it `NEXT_PUBLIC_MARVEL_API_PUBLIC_KEY`

NextJS has [docs here](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/configuring/environment-variables), including some useful stuff about referencing other vars inside your `.env*` files